# Objective-C String Differences

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

What's the difference between `NSString *myString = @"Johnny Appleseed"` versus `NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithString: @"Johnny Appleseed"]`?

Where's a good case to use either one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first case, you are getting a pointer to a constant `NSString`.  As long as your program runs, `myString` will be a valid pointer.  In the second, you are creating an autoreleased `NSString` object with a constant string as a template.  In that case, `myString` won't point to a real object anymore after the current run loop ends.

Edit:  As many people have noted, the *normal* implementation of `stringWithString:` just returns a pointer to the constant string, so under normal circumstances, your two examples are exactly the same.   There is a bit of a subtle difference in that Objective-C allows methods of a class to be replaced using categories and allows whole classes to be replaced with `class_poseAs`.  In those cases, you might run into a non-default implementation of `stringWithString:`, which may have different semantics than you expect it to.  Just because it *happens to be* that the default implementation does the same thing as a simple assignment doesn't mean that you should rely on subtle implementation-specific behaviour in your program - use the right case for the particular job you're trying to do.

Comment: -1 Have you tried this?  I think you'll find that stringWithString: with a constant string parameter just returns the constant string.

Comment: @JeremyP, if you look at the discussion under @quixoto's answer below, there is some more explanation of what I was getting at.  I guess I should edit this one for clarity.

Answer (score 5):

The other answers here are correct. A case where you *would* use `+stringWithString:` is to obtain an immutable copy of a string which might be mutable.

Answer (score 2):

Other than syntax and a very very minor difference in performance, **nothing**. The both produce the exact same pointer to the exact same object.

Use the first example. It's easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

In practice, nothing. You wouldn't ever use the second form, really, unless you had some special reason to. And I can't think of any right now.

(See Carl's answer for the technical difference.)

Comment: In practice there is a definite difference in the lifetime of each object, and when `myString` points to a real object and when it doesn't.

Comment: @carl: They both produce the same pointer value. No difference in the lifetime as both point to the exact same data in memory.

Comment: @jojaba - potentially not if there's a class posing as `NSString` or someone has overriden `stringWithString` in a category - seems dangerous to make assumptions like that.

Comment: @carl Sure, but that is not what he asked. He asked the differences between the two statements. And beside, you can pose as different type in his first example too.

Comment: @jojaba, exactly.  I guess the difference *really* comes down to that there is a method called in one case and not in the other.  Maybe that's a better way for me to have explained it.